# program that replaces values without another variable

Tags: c++

I have an exercise to write a function that replaces values with no third variable, I tried some solutions but did not get them all.

I wrote the following code:

```
void swap1(int* p1, int* p2) {
    p1++;
    *p1 = *p2;

    p1--;
    *p2 = *p1;

    p1++;    
    cout << *p1 << endl;
}
```

**main:**

```
    int main() {
    int n1 = 5, n2 = 8;

    cout << "before swap: " << endl;
    cout << "value 1: " << n1 << " value 2: " << n2 << endl;

    swap1(&n1, &n2);

    cout << "after swap: " << endl;
    cout << "value 1: " << n1 << " value 2: " << n2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
before swap:
value 1: 5 value 2: 8
8
after swap:
value 1: 5 value 2: 5
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why when I print inside my function this really swap the values, but in `main` not?

What's wrong?

`*p1 = p1++;` >> why not work? (that what I try to do in theory)

Comment: What you're doing is *wrong* and *undefined behavior*.

Comment: how's that supposed to work? explain.

Comment: This line of code `p1++;`  does not do what you think it does, I believe. 1. that's effectively using a third variable and 2. who owns the memory you now point p1 at?

Comment: `std::swap` and exercise is done.

Comment: @crashmstr typically these types of homework are to make you think about how `std::swap` works, not to simply delegate to it

Comment: Hint: when using `int` one possible solution is using `XOR` ( `^` ).

Comment: As for a possible solution, haven't you thought about that `n2` may be *before* `n1` on the stack of the `main` function? It will still be UB by using your method, but it might work for your current compiler and operating system. Just don't expect it to work everywhere, even upgrading your compiler might change it.

Comment: @SteveTownsend looking at an implementation now. It uses a temporary. So they fail the exercise?

Answer (score 4):

No overflow.

See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-two-numbers-without-using-temporary-variable/

```
 int main() {

    int n1 = 5, n2 = 8;


    cout << "before swap: " << endl;
    cout << "value 1: " << n1 << " value 2: " << n2 << endl;

     n2 = n1^n2;
     n1 = n1^n2;
     n2 = n1^n2;

    cout << "after swap: " << endl;
    cout << "value 1: " << n1 << " value 2: " << n2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to avoid xor if they are equal?  The first xor will set n2 to zero, n1 xor 0 is still n1, and the final xor will be n xor 0 which is the original (equal) value.  It all just works.

Comment: @MartinBonner. Thanks. While reading my link, they show a case when swapping pointers to the same address. In that case you have a problem. I misread it.

Comment: Ah!.  Yes if `&n1` == `&n2`, bad things will happen :-)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested from the previous answers... simply put in a form as the one you proposed:

```
void swap2(int* p1, int* p2) {
  if(p1 != p2) {
    *p2 = (*p1)^(*p2);
    *p1 = (*p1)^(*p2);
    *p2 = (*p1)^(*p2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 int main() {

    int n1 = 5, n2 = 8;


    cout << "before swap: " << endl;
    cout << "value 1: " << n1 << " value 2: " << n2 << endl;

     n2 = n1+n2;
     n1 = n2 -n1;
    n2 = n2-n1;


    cout << "after swap: " << endl;
    cout << "value 1: " << n1 << " value 2: " << n2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour if `n1+n2` overflows.